# find the next day using java

Tags: java

plz I want your help with java program

this program ask user to enter (day,month,year) of current day and give him the next day (day,month year ) .
for example :

```
enter the day: 28
enter the month: 2
enter the year: 2014

the next day is: 1/3/2014
```

Comment: you want to write you whole program? have you tried yourself?

Comment: Consider using a `GregorianCalendar`. Btw; question is not specific to netbeans (concerning the tag).

Comment: get a Calendar instance, use `Calendar.set(int year, int month, int date)` , to set the input date and use `add(int field, int amount)` to increment the desired field

Answer (score 0):

Use `Calendar.add` to add one day to current date. Sample code here:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
System.out.println(c.getTime().toString());
```